# Definitions of $\epsilon$-regular partition

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I am wondering about the equivalence between two definitions of an *$\epsilon$-regular partition* of a graph.

First of all, if $G$ is a graph and $A$ and $B$ are subsets of its vertex set, the *density* of edges between $A$ and $B$ is defined as 
$$d(A,B)=\frac{|E(A,B)|}{|A||B|},$$
where $|E(A,B)|$ is the number of edges between $A$ and $B$.

Given some $\epsilon>0$, the pair $(A,B)$ is said to be $\epsilon$-regular if, for every $A'\subseteq A$ and $B'\subseteq B$ with $|A'|\geq \epsilon |A|$ and $|B'|\geq \epsilon |B|$, we have that
$$|d(A',B')-d(A,B)|\leq \epsilon.$$

Now, what we want to do next is to define what it means for a partition of the vertex set to be $\epsilon$-regular, and I have found two different definitions (from different sources).

> **Definition 1.** Given a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices and an $\epsilon>0$, a partition $\{X_1, \dots, X_k\}$ of its vertex set is *$\epsilon$-regular* if
>   $$\sum \frac{|X_i||X_j|}{n^2} \leq \epsilon,$$
>   where the sum is taken over all pairs $(X_i,X_j)$ which are *not* $\epsilon$-regular.
>
> **Definition 2.** Given a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices and an $\epsilon>0$, a partition $\{V_0, V_1, \dots, V_k\}$ of its vertex set $V$ is *$\epsilon$-regular* if:
>
> - $|V_0|\leq \epsilon |V|$
> - $|V_1| = \dots = |V_k|$
> - at most $\epsilon\binom{k}{2}$ pairs $(V_i,V_j)$ are not $\epsilon$-regular.

I am assuming that these definitions are equivalent, and they are both used in various different sources in order to prove Szemeredi's regularity lemma, but I cannot see if that is indeed true.

Can anyone help?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to check that for each $\epsilon>0$ each graph, which is $\epsilon$-regular according to Definition 2 is $\epsilon$-regular according to Definition 1. But not conversely, because according to Definition 1, any partition of any finite graph is $1$-regular, whereas Definition 2 imposes additional restrictions on the sizes of partition members.